# Matching records between two tables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the below code to do matching between two different tables. The code only updates the first record as "Matched".

I want to compare each record in ID field from T1 if it present in T2, e.g. To check if A present in T2 then go to next record in T1 and check B if it present in T2 through loop until all records in T1 matched

```
Table 1

ID
A
B
C

Table 2

ID
A
B

Expected Matching Results

ID 
A
B
```

Any help please

```
   If rs2("ID").Value = rs1("ID").Value Then
        rs2.MoveNext()
        Do While Not rs2.EOF()

            rs1("Matching").Value = "Matched"
            rs1.Update()
            rs2.MoveFirst()
        Loop

    End If
```

Comment: This looks like an endless loop to me: given that `rs2` has records, `rs2.MoveFirst` will go to the first record, EOF becomes false, and `Do While Not rs2.EOF()` will never end.

Comment: @Peter B Please advise with correct code

Comment: It is unclear how you want to match. E.g. compare first row of T1 with first row of T2, then compare second row of T1 with second row of T2, etc? Or is it a match if an ID from T1 is present anywhere in T2? Don't expect us to guess what your problem statement is, you need to be clear and complete about it.

Comment: @Peter B I want to compare each record in ID field from T1 if it present in T2, e.g. To check if A present in T2 then go to next record in T1 and check B if it present in T2 through loop until all records in T1 matched with T2

Comment: Doing this with a loop may be a 'fun' exercise, but it will be a lot simpler and more efficient if you just let SQL do the work: `UPDATE T1 SET Matching = 'Matched' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID)`

Comment: i need it though loop can you help with correct code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your problem correctly, you just want to update the "Matching" column in T1 if there's a corresponding ID record in T2. Doing this in SQL would be ideal, as Peter said.

If you really want to loop, Peter is correct that you have an endless loop: you exit when you hit the end of the record set, but at the end of each iteration you are resetting back to the first record.

I don't know why you are looping through rs2 when you already found a match. Once you know that `rs1("ID").Value = rs2("ID").Value` then just update the Matching record in rs1 and call `rs2.MoveFirst()` so you can start back at the top when trying to find a match for the next ID in T1. No loop is required here.

Comment: The loop is required  as each value in table 1 should be matched with all values in table 2 and put "Matched" for matched records